# Access props inside quotes in React JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

In JSX, how do you reference a value from `props` from inside a quoted attribute value?

For example:

```html
<img className="image" src="images/{this.props.image}" />
```

The resulting HTML output is:

```html
<img class="image" src="images/{this.props.image}">
```

Answer (score 512, accepted):

React (or JSX) doesn't support variable interpolation inside an attribute value, but you can put any JS expression inside curly braces as the entire attribute value, so this works:

```html
<img className="image" src={"images/" + this.props.image} />
```

Comment: what about backtips in es6?

Comment: @DavidLavieri See Cristi's answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/30061326/70345 below.

Answer (score 247):

If you want to use the es6 template literals, you need braces around the tick marks as well:

```
<img className="image" src={`images/${this.props.image}`} />
```

Comment: future ES6 Template literals

Comment: The string enclosed by backticks is a "template literal": https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 51):

If you're using JSX with Harmony, you could do this:

```
<img className="image" src={`images/${this.props.image}`} />
```

Here you are writing the value of `src` as an expression.

Comment: this is something that's hard to find. and for reusable containers this is a-must-know

Comment: Just so that people don't get confused with mentioning of Harmony, this is a part of [ES6 standard](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-template-literal-lexical-components), while answer is dated few months before it became a standard.

Answer (score 18):

Instead of adding variables and strings, you can use the ES6 template strings!
Here is an example:

```
<img className="image" src={`images/${this.props.image}`} />
```

As for all other JavaScript components inside JSX, use template strings inside of curly braces. To "inject" a variable use a dollar sign followed by curly braces containing the variable you would like to inject. For example:

```
{`string ${variable} another string`}
```

Answer (score 8):

Best practices are to add getter method for that :

```
getImageURI() {
  return "images/" + this.props.image;
}

<img className="image" src={this.getImageURI()} />
```

Then , if you have more logic later on, you can maintain the code smoothly.

Answer (score 2):

For People, looking for answers w.r.t to 'map' function and dynamic data, here is a working example.

```
<img src={"http://examole.com/randomview/images" + each_actor['logo']} />
```

This gives the URL as "http://examole.com/randomview/images/2/dp_pics/182328.jpg" (random example)

Answer (score 2):

You can do like this

```
<img className="img" src=`images/${this.props.image}`>
```

Answer (score 1):

Note: In react you can put javascript expression inside curly bracket. We can use this property in this example.
Note: give one look to below example:

```
class LoginForm extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {i:1};
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({i : prevState.i + 1}));

    console.log(this.state.j);  
  }


  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <p onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>Click to change image</p>
        <img src={'images/back'+ this.state.i+'.jpg'}/>
      </div>
      );

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Best Option for Dynamic className or Props , just do some concatenation like we do in Javascript.

```
     className={
        "badge " +
        (this.props.value ? "badge-primary " : "badge-danger ") +
        " m-4"
      }
```

Comment: I'd recommend uses `classnames` package for building dynamic classNames

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
<img className="image" src=`images/${this.props.image}`>
```

or

```
<img className="image" src={'images/'+this.props.image}>
```

or

```
  render() {
         let imageUrl = this.props.image ? "images/"+this.props.image : 'some placeholder url image';
    return (
       <div>
          <img className="image" src={imageUrl} />
       </div>
    )
  }
```