# React using JS var inside quotes

Tags: reactjs

I just started learning React using tutorials on [React site](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html#hook-up-the-data-model)

I wanted to use ids for each element inside JSON array. After referring to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21668025/react-jsx-access-props-in-quotes), I tried `<div className="commentListElement" key={key} id={"comment-"+{key}} >` it in my code, but it didn't work.

> It shows `comment-[object Object]`

And sadly `${key}` is also not working...!

Here's my code:

```
  var data = [
    {id: 1, author: "Pete Hunt", text: "Sample Comment 1"},
    {id: 2, author: "Virginia Woolf", text: "Sample Comment 2"}
  ]

  var CommentList = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
      var commentNodes = this.props.data.map(function(comment, key) {
        return (
          <div className="commentListElement" key={key} id={"comment-"+{key}} >
          Key: {key} <br />
          ID: {comment.id} <br />
          Commented by {comment.author} <br />
          Comment: {comment.text}
          </div>
        );
      });
      return (
        <div className="commentList">
          {commentNodes}
        </div>
      );
    }
  })

  var CommentBox = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
      return (
        <div className="commentBox">
          Hello, world! I am a CommentBox.
          <CommentList data={data} />
        </div>
      );
    }
  });
  ReactDOM.render(
    <CommentBox />,
    document.getElementById('content')
  );
```

But I see this in my browser

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In JSX inside curly braces you should write javascript expression, so that this should work:

```
id={"comment-"+key}
```

Furthermore it is not a good practice to use array indexes as keys of react elements. You should use some kind of business identifier e.g. `comment.id`.

Comment: array indexes works just fine as long as you prefix  or suffix to make it unique because not in every case you have unique Id