# React JSX: Access Props in Quotes in a Maped component list

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, quotes, jsx

I am trying to display profile images from a list of profiles using the indivdual's profile props but I can not reach the props in the setup for some reason. It works fine for the name and title but when I try to use the profileimage url as source it reads as undefined if I use the example from the answer here [React JSX: Access Props in Quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21668025/react-jsx-access-props-in-quotes)

```
<img className="image" src={`images/${this.props.image}`} />
```

this does not work for me when used in this code

```
 <ul className={styles.ListUl}> {this.props.clinicians.map(c => {
   return (              
     <li key={c.accountId}>
       <button onClick={this.handleSetIndividual.bind(this, c)}>
         <h4>{c.firstName} {c.lastName}</h4>
         <img src={`${c.profileImageUrl}`} alt="individualImage" height="100" width="100" />
        </button> </li>
     )}
   )}
 </ul>
```

All other props work such as the names this just has to do with getting the src param access to those props.

using `src={c.profileImageUrl}`  as you suggested was tried already and is read by the browser as absolutely nothing. As in there is no src param any more. like this:

```
<img alt="profileImage" height="100" width="100">
```

The way I did it `` src={`${c.profileImageUrl}`} ``  is read as `src="undefined"`
if I take the `$` symbol off of it it reads `src="c.profileImageUrl"`

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: What do you mean "this does not work for me"? AKA, what is the specific error that you're getting?

Comment: If you `console.log(c);` before you return, do you see `profileImageUrl` as a defined property on that object? It could be you have different case or a typo somewhere. Also, you can simplify that image line by making it:

`<img src={c.profileImageUrl} alt="individualImage" height="100" width="100" />`

Comment: I updated the question  to give you the specific browser issues for each format.